# Как реализовать формулу для расчета даты?

Tags: javascript, php, база-данных, joomla, формулы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать следующее.

Необходимо, чтобы на сайте в разделе "Акции" в формате обычного текста, было предложение "В период с (дата_старта) по (дата_окончания) у нас проходит акция ..."

Условием является расчет первой и второй даты от текущего числа.
Дата старта - минус пять дней от текущего числа. Дата окончания - плюс пять дней от текущего числа.
При этом, необходимо, чтобы информация обновлялась автоматически по достижению даты окончания, рассчитывая по формуле: (дата старта) = (текущее число) - (5 дней), (дата окончания) = (текущая дата) + (5 дней)

Например, сегодня 20 октября, рассчитываем по формуле и получаем "В период с 15 октября по 25 октября у нас проходит акция...", а по достижению 25 октября идет перерасчет заново.

Большое спасибо за Ваши ответы! Сайт на Joomla CMS.
Подсказали вот такой вариант, но я не знаю, как вывести это в Joomla:

```html
Во-первых нужно хранить где-нибудь дату начала, конца акции и дату когда нужно обновить эти значения..

//$date_from_db - дата из БД

if ($date_from_db > time()){
    $start_date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime('-5 days'));
    $end_date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime('+5 days'));

    $date_from_db = time();

    // Тут сохранить все три значения в базу
}
```

Comment: Почему перерасчет должен быть 25-го, а не 21-го?

Comment: @Эникейщик так попросил клиент, чтобы доверие клиента не подрывалось, как мне объяснили :)

Comment: @Эникейщик акция будет на постоянке на целой сетке сайтов, в ручную просто будет очень долго менять даты

Comment: Я к тому, что каким образом определяется, что день, от которого считается - сегодня, а не, например, вчера, если каждый раз отнимается/прибавляется 5 дней от текущей даты. Задание противоречивое.

Comment: Например, от серверного времени, просто задавать перерасчет формулы один раз в необходимое кол-во времени

Comment: Да серверное время ничем не отличается от остального. Просто сделайте "акцию" с 5 по 15, с 15 по 25 и с 25 по 5 и в зависимости от текущей даты показывайте один текст из трех. И не надо никаких вычислений :)

Comment: @Эникейщик вот это сейчас инсайт был для меня)) А ведь точно, всего надо три текста..